# how to check if all the keys of a immutable map have value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, immutable.js

```
const [fieldValues, updateFieldValues] = useState(fromJS({
    imageName: '',
    tags: [],
    password: '',
  }));

const handleButtonClick = () => { 
  const res = // logic to find which field/fields are empty
}
```

how can i validate if all the keys have value ?
p.s: i have the following requirements.

1. imageName and password should have at least one character.
2. tags should have at least one item.

Comment: You can use the `length` property for Strings and Arrays. `[].length == 0` and `"".length == 0`. A string or array with at least one character or element will have `length` greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) a javascript library to vaidate values using a pre defined schema. Or else you can write a function that returns the keys of object that doesnt meet requirements

**CUSTOM JS METHOD**

```
  function validateObj(obj) {
let isValid = true;
const errorKeys = [];
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) =>{
  if(!value) {
    errorKeys.push(key)
    isValid = false;
    return;
  }
  if(Array.isArray(value)) {
    if(!value?.length) {
      errorKeys.push(key)
    isValid = false;
    return;
    }
  }

})
return { isValid, errorKeys }
}
```

**IMMUTABLE JS METHOD**

```
 function validateObj(obj) {
    let isValid = true;
    const errorKeys = [];
    console.log(obj)
    obj.mapEntries(([key, value]) =>{
    console.log(key, value)
      if(!value) {
        errorKeys.push(key)
        isValid = false;
        return;
      }
      if(List.isList(value)) {
        if(!value.size) {
          errorKeys.push(key)
        isValid = false;
        return;
        }
      }

    })
    return { isValid, errorKeys }
    }
```

**USAGE:**

```
const handleButtonClick = () => { 
  const { isValid, errorKeys } = validateObj(obj);
  if(!isValid) {
    // SHOW ERROR MESSAGE HERE
  }
}
```

Please feel free to reach out in case of any issues/ doubts

**EDIT:** [Link to example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2v8umxr4/24/)

Comment: @ Sumanth Madishetty Hi there. I really appreciate your valuable feedback but I am actually using a library called immutable.js on a React.js project.
https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/

Comment: @noobBokhonto Have updated the answer with immutable-js

Answer (score 0):

Immutable.js Collections are [Iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), so you can use `for ... of` and other common interactions on them. It also offers many ways of looking at the data, like `forEach, find, findKey, findValue, filter`. Take a look at the [docs](https://immutable-js-oss.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map), they are good. A few examples can be seen below:

```js
const thing = Immutable.fromJS({
  banana: 'scale',  
  imageName: '',
  tags: [],
  password: '',
});

for([key, val] of thing) {
 console.log('for of', key, ':', val);
}

thing.forEach((key, val) => {
  console.log('forEach', key, ':', val);
});

const firstItemIdoNotLike = thing.findKey((key, val) => {
  if(!!val) {
    return true;
  }
  if (val.hasOwnProperty('length')) {
    return val.length < 1;
  }
  return false;
});

if (firstItemIdoNotLike) {
  console.log('validation error on', firstItemIdoNotLike);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.12/immutable.js"></script>
```